# Laravel Sail - No docker-compose.yml file found, using WSL 2

Tags: php, laravel, docker, wsl-2, laravel-sail

After successfully making WSL2 work with Docker Desktop (v3.1.0)

```sh
 NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

I followed steps from the Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-windows but the error:

```sh
[ErrorException]
  file_get_contents(): Read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied
```

showed up, and i couldn't find the `docker-compose.yml` file in the directory either, after running `./vendor/bin/sail up`:

```sh
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: Please share more details - does that permission error tell you more? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to resolve `Read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied`, it seemed to be a Composer problem, so i updated it, then run `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`, same things happened. FYI, this happens before the whole process ends(before `cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up)

Comment: For me the problem was with unstable internet connection. Retrying installing the laravel fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a Linux permission problem. The safest way to fix it is to `chown` the directory and make it owned by the same user / group as the php process is running under.

The default user is called sail: https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/Dockerfile#L46

And the group is read from a .env variable called `WWWGROUP`

So what you want to do is open your WSL2 console, cd to your project.
And run

```sh
chown -R sail:<whatever your group from the env is WWWGROUP> .
```

`.` means current directory.

Many beginners would do things like `chmod 777`, however [this is a bad practise](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777).